# Inherit List in Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, office365

I would like to create many lists from a base list using Sharepoint. This is alone, is pretty easy. But, the problem is when I edit/add/delete a column in the base list. The changes in the base list does not reflect on the other lists. Is it possible to make a base list and inherit the columns in other lists and stay with the same columns on all lists?

Until now, I managed to create lists from an existing one. But it will not stay with the same columns when the reference list has columns modified.

Example of desired effect:

List 0: No content, just columns definition

List 1: content 1, columns must be always the same as List 0

List 2: content 2, columns must be always the same as List 0

List 3: content 3, columns must be always the same as List 0

Comment: Hello, that is exactly the purpose of a Content Type with site columns.

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating new custom lists using existing SharePoint lists using below option, it will not work for your requirements:

[image]

**Workaround**:

1. Create common site columns required in your site as per your requirements
2. Create a custom content type inheriting from SharePoint default "Item" content type
3. Every time you create a new list, add the custom content type in your list and hide default Item content type.
4. Next time when you edit the site column settings and force the changes to children columns, it will be automatically updated/synced in all lists.

Check below documentation(s) for more information:

1. [Introduction to content types and content type publishing](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/introduction-to-content-types-and-content-type-publishing-e1277a2e-a1e8-4473-9126-91a0647766e5)